# Turning a nested foreach into a closure?

Tags: php, solr, closures

I'm just trying to make this a little reusable as I know I will need it again, I'm curious as to how I would accomplish it? The `$solr->addDocuments($bleh)` can be left out if needed.

```
$solr = New SolrClient([
    'hostname' => $config->Solr->hostname,
    'wt'       => $config->Solr->response,
    'port'     => $config->Solr->port,
    'path'     => $config->Solr->path,
]);

$docsArray = [];
foreach ($recordset AS $key => $array)
{
    $docsArray[$key] = New SolrInputDocument();

    foreach($array AS $id => $value)

        $docsArray[$key]->addField($id,  $value);
}

$solr->addDocuments($docsArray);
```

**UPDATE**

If I can get a method(s) that will recursively add these into a `Solr->addField($k, $v, $i);` I can settle with that! The key here is to recursively add Solr fields

Comment: [array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)?

Comment: that would work, but it also wouldn't be a closure. +1 none the less.

Comment: array_walk_recursive() takes a closure as an argument, what exactly are you after?

Comment: @MarkBaker Something like this: http://pastebin.com/WpbAstPz

Comment: Mind you that is a horrible none working example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

break; Will break a loop of any type, or a switch statement.